# Is there a way to change the indentation behavior of the postfix operator //?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting, customization

For example, using newlines after `//` results in some really weird indentation:

[image]

Ideally, I'd love to be able to do something like this:

```
x //
f1 //
f2 //
f3 //
f4 //
f5
```

or if possible, this would be even better:

```
x
// f1
// f2
// f3
// f4
// f5
```

Comment: The last one is not possible because `x` on a line by itself is already a complete expression.  `x//` is not a complete expression, so Mathematica will keep reading more from the next time.  Similarly, `x`, newline, `+y` is two different expressions and not equivalent to `x+`, newline, `y`, i.e. `x+y`.  If a line ends with a backslash, Mathematica *will* keep reading on the next line, but make sure no spaces follow the backslash.  This is just a comment, I don't know the answer to your main question.  You can use `Code` cells which don't indent at all but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: I cannot recall seeing anything that would let us modify this indentation behavior but I like the question.

Comment: `x // RightComposition[
  f1,
  f2,
  f3,
  f4,
  f5]` can have a relatively good appearance. `x //
 f1 /*
  f2 /*
  f3 /*
  f4 /*
  f5` unfortunately doesn't.

Comment: This would make a lot of sense considering all the operator forms introduced in v10.  The current indentation behaviour for `//` is quite useless.  Have you suggested this to Wolfram?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`InputAutoReplacements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAutoReplacements) with a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) to achieve the desired behavior:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAutoReplacements,"//"}] = TemplateBox[
    {},
    "Postfix",
    DisplayFunction->("//"&),
    InterpretationFunction->("//"&),
    SyntaxForm->"\[VerticalSeparator]"
];
```

The key is to change the [`SyntaxForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxForm) to a symbol that doesn't indent in the undesired fashion, which is most operators. However, it is necessary to use a symbol whose parsing precedence is lower than the default parsing precedence of "//".

Here's a portion of the [precedence table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms#15012) from the documentation:

[image]

The above explains why I chose `\[VerticalSeparator]`for the [`SyntaxForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxForm) setting. Now, using `//` produces the following (as an image so you can see it in action):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A rough approximation using a string

```
toExpr[str_String] := 
  str //
    StringReplace[#, "\n" :> ""] & //
   ToExpression;

"
 x
 //f1
 //f2
 //f3
 //f4
 //f5
 " //
 toExpr
```

> f5[f4[f3[f2[f1[x]]]]]

Although, this is just a `Composition`

```
Composition[f5, f4, f3, f2, f1]@x
```

> f5[f4[f3[f2[f1[x]]]]]

```
f5@*f4@*f3@*f2@*f1@x
```

> f5[f4[f3[f2[f1[x]]]]]

```
% == %% == %%%
```

> True